# Spring boot logging with log4.properties file in not working

Tags: spring, spring-boot, log4j

I have log4j.properties file under resources folder.  Now I am passing logging.file=/Users/jkuriakos/web/rnt/dr/rnt.log in application.properties file.
 How can I use the log4j.properties file to load all information (like smtp server etc) from log4j.properties file?

Answer (score 0):

Exclude the spring-boot-starter-logging from your pom file and add following dependency:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-log4j</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

This should make spring boot pick up log4j.properties from resources folder.
http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-logging.html#howto-configure-log4j-for-logging

Comment: Thank you. I fixed it by adding it in build.gradle like,configurations {
    all*.exclude module : 'spring-boot-starter-logging'
}and by adding compile ('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-log4j') in to the dependencies. Now I have another issue. How can I do the same exclude from the main class. Below is my main class.

@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {
 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
  SpringApplication.run(Application.class);
 }}