# External Log4j.properties in not printing logs - spring boot 2.2.1

Tags: spring, spring-boot, log4j

Develop a spring boot application in `2.2.1 RELEASE`.Everything is working fine except Loging using log4j.properties.

In `apoplication.properies`, added logging.config as given below

```
logging.config =${external.config}/log4j.properties.
```

Pom.xml file,excluded `spring-boot-starter-logging` and added `spring-boot-starter-log4j` as given below

```
   <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-log4j2</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

log4j.properties

```
log4j.rootLogger=error,Service  
# Direct log messages to a log file
log4j.appender.Service=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.Service.File=C:/log/Service.log
log4j.appender.Service.MaxFileSize=1MB
log4j.appender.Service.MaxBackupIndex=1
log4j.appender.Service.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.Service.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - [%X{AUDIT_USER}] %m%n
```

i referred following links in stack

1.[Logger not printing with log4j.properties within Spring Boot 1.5.7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53041047/logger-not-printing-with-log4j-properties-within-spring-boot-1-5-7)

2.[Spring boot logging with log4.properties file in not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33248104/spring-boot-logging-with-log4-properties-file-in-not-working)

**Edit 1**

As `Andy Wilkinson` comments, i modified `log4j.properties`  file content and file name, file name should be `log4j2.properties`.

I tried to log some string to log file as given below

```
public class ServiceMain {

    private static final Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(ServiceMain.class);
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        SpringApplication.run(ServiceMain.class, args);
        logger.debug("----------------------Stating spring booot----------------------");



    }

}
```

debug log `"----------------------Stating spring booot----------------------"` wont write to `c:/log/service.log`

Log file

```
2019-11-22 05:20:14,631 INFO o.s.b.StartupInfoLogger [main] Starting ServiceMain v7.0.0.0 on host-4 with PID 119176 (D:\Service\target\Service-1.0.jar started by Administrator in D:\Service\target)
2019-11-22 05:20:14,634 DEBUG o.s.b.StartupInfoLogger [main] Running with Spring Boot v2.2.1.RELEASE, Spring v5.2.1.RELEASE
2019-11-22 05:20:14,635 INFO o.s.b.SpringApplication [main] The following profiles are active: Service
2019-11-22 05:20:24,898 INFO o.s.b.StartupInfoLogger [main] Started ServiceMain in 12.312 seconds (JVM running for 14.189)
```

Did i miss any `log4j2.properties` configuration?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using Log4j 2 (which you should be as version 1 is no longer supported) but appear to be configuring it using a Log4j 1 configuration file.

You can learn more about Log4j 2’s configuration properties in its [documentation](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/configuration.html#Properties). It includes this example:

```
status = error
dest = err
name = PropertiesConfig

property.filename = target/rolling/rollingtest.log

filter.threshold.type = ThresholdFilter
filter.threshold.level = debug

appender.console.type = Console
appender.console.name = STDOUT
appender.console.layout.type = PatternLayout
appender.console.layout.pattern = %m%n
appender.console.filter.threshold.type = ThresholdFilter
appender.console.filter.threshold.level = error

appender.rolling.type = RollingFile
appender.rolling.name = RollingFile
appender.rolling.fileName = ${filename}
appender.rolling.filePattern = target/rolling2/test1-%d{MM-dd-yy-HH-mm-ss}-%i.log.gz
appender.rolling.layout.type = PatternLayout
appender.rolling.layout.pattern = %d %p %C{1.} [%t] %m%n
appender.rolling.policies.type = Policies
appender.rolling.policies.time.type = TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy
appender.rolling.policies.time.interval = 2
appender.rolling.policies.time.modulate = true
appender.rolling.policies.size.type = SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy
appender.rolling.policies.size.size=100MB
appender.rolling.strategy.type = DefaultRolloverStrategy
appender.rolling.strategy.max = 5

logger.rolling.name = com.example.my.app
logger.rolling.level = debug
logger.rolling.additivity = false
logger.rolling.appenderRef.rolling.ref = RollingFile

rootLogger.level = info
rootLogger.appenderRef.stdout.ref = STDOUT
```